# How do I get time duration in C

Tags: c, timer, time.h

Let's say I have a thread that handles a HTTP connection using a socket, I need to somehow get the how long it took to process this connection. (timeAfterConnection - timeBeforeConnection).

I know I can use API like timer_gettime but after Googled around I did not find any working example about how to do this.

Can anybody give me an example of getting time elapse in C code?

Comment: Do you want it in C or C++? It matters as the answers may vary wildly.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/now

Comment: I don't think you want timer_gettime. Try clock_gettime. You just need to call it before and after the connection and subtract the two times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <time.h>

struct timespec before, after;
long elapsed_nsecs;

clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &before);

/* handle connection */

clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &after);

elapsed_nsecs = (after.tv_sec - before.tv_sec) * 1000000000 +
                (after.tv_nsec - before.tv_nsec);
```

Comment: Working perfectly on Linux box. But not so on Mac OSX (use of undeclared identifier 'CLOCK_REALTIME'). Is there a way to get to work on a Mac?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there. Know nothing about OSX :-)